# Adding anchor to all wordpress links

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm looking for solutnion how to add anchor automaticly to all links inside wordpress. I want to avoid on some pages to opening page directly on top. Want to move some new opened pages below slider directly to content. So i have an  quick idea to prepare some function for add an anchor on the end of all links and than just put anchor in the code were i want. But i need help how to do it in best way. Or maybe somebody have beter solution?

how it is:
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'
how i need:
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#anchor'

thx!

Comment: You're talking about adding an anchor to "all" wordpress links, then you're talking about "some pages". That doesn't make much sense. So, you probably want to create a mapping for page/post → anchor name. You can then add filter handlers for `post_link`, `post_type_link`, and `page_link` and match those against the mapping. If there is an entry in the mapping, let the filter function append the appropriate anchor to the link. However: if links are generated in any other way than by a permalink (e.g., someone puts a hardcoded link into a post) this will not apply to those, either.

Comment: That true. Question was not clear. To prepare working anchor we have to put #anchor to link and anchor tag into page somewhere <a href="anchor">. That i mean. And i want to add #anchor to all links to be able to put <a href="anchor"> only on "some pages" where i want.